# Android : Custom dialog before Notification Permission

Tags: android, notifications, android-13

Is it possible to show a custom dialog message before  when asking for notification permissions android. basically on click of ok button from dialog, it should open the notification icon.attached notification popup for reference:

[image]

Comment: You could check if user granted notification permissions. if not, you can show a dialog and when user clicks on ok button, show the permission one

Comment: This is not possible as Notification permission is not a runtime permission

Comment: Ideally i shouldn't see the notification. My app is still on android-31 but my phone is on android 33 and thats why its showing up. But how to control the trigger of the notification as I want to show a policy before it. On accept button, it should show notification permission.